# Why is the grid not forming?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The grid is not forming correctly. How do I fix this?

I've tried making the id of paragraphs letters instead of numbers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
<style>
.board {
    background-image: url("board.jpg");
    border-style: solid;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
.pit {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor = "beige">
<div class = "board">
<div class = "pit"><p id = "1">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "2">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "3">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "4">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "5">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "6">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "7">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "8">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "9">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "10">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "11">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "12">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "13">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "14">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "15">4</p></div>
<div class = "pit"><p id = "16">4</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the paragraphs to be in a grid pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I do not have your board image.

The `display: grid;` and the `grid-template-columns: auto ...` move into the board style to act as a container.

Then style the `pit` to be "cells" within the grid.

I changed your styles to:

```
<style>
.board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    background-image: url("board.jpg");
    border-style: solid;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.pit {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Which made it look like this: (of course, this may need tweaking to match your needs)
[image]

Which was loosely based on an example of using grid [from here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid).

Answer (score 0):

Give your `.board` this rule `grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr)`. Then make your `.pit` divs type `flex` and center the content in each one. Your ids can't start with a digit, btw:

```css
.board {
   background-image: url("board.jpg");
   border-style: solid;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.pit{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="1">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="2">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="3">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="4">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="5">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="6">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="7">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="8">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="9">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="10">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="11">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="12">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="13">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="14">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="15">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pit">
    <p id="16">4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```